# Reduce the Bluetooth range of android device programmatically in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, esp32

I am working on the mobile android application and my phone successfully connects to the ESP32 microcontroller. The ESP32's bluetooth range is high and I want to disconnect my phone's bluetooth if the distance/range between the phone and the hardware is more than 10 meters. I cannot modify ESP32's code to reduce the power range, so is there any way I can reduce the bluetooth's range or make my phone disconnect automatically if it goes above a specific range? Please find my android studio code below that I have so far:

```js
public class ConnectedDevice extends AppCompatActivity {    
    
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private boolean isBtConnected = false;
    private BluetoothDisconnect bluetoothDisconnect;
    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");        

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected_device);                
        new ConnectBT().execute();

        btnDis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DisconnectOnBtnClick();
            }
        });

        bluetoothDisconnect = new BluetoothDisconnect();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(bluetoothDisconnect, intentFilter);

        mButtonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectedDevice.this, PairedDevices.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    protected  void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(bluetoothDisconnect);
}

    
    private void DisconnectOnBtnClick() {

        if (mReadThread != null) {
            mReadThread.stop();
            do {

            } while (mReadThread.isRunning());
            mReadThread = null;
        }
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not disconnect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finish();
    }

    private void sendSMS() {
        try {
            message = brand + " " + model + " " + licensePlate;
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage("5089715596",null,message,null,null);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not send message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    private class BluetoothDisconnect extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            sendSMS();
            startTimer();

            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                mButtonStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(ConnectedDevice.this, "Calling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                callNumber();
            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStop.setText("Stop");
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void callNumber()
    {
        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5088631994"));
        startActivity(phoneIntent);
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    
    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private boolean ConnectSuccess = true;

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute () {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ConnectedDevice.this, "Connecting...", "Please Wait!!!");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground (Void... devices) {
            try {
                if ( btSocket==null || !isBtConnected ) {
                    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    remoteDevice = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    btSocket = remoteDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    btSocket.connect();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                ConnectSuccess = false;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!ConnectSuccess) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed. Make sure your device is in range", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            else {
                isBtConnected = true;
                mReadThread = new ReadInput();
                getCurrentData();
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculated using rssi intensity and power values

```
public double getDistance(int measuredPower, double rssi) {
            if (rssi >= 0) {
                return -1.0;
            }
            if (measuredPower == 0) {
                return -1.0;
            }
            double ratio = rssi * 1.0 / measuredPower;
            if (ratio < 1.0) {
                return Math.pow(ratio, 10);
            } else {
                double distance= (0.42093) * Math.pow(ratio, 6.9476) + 0.54992;
                return distance;
            }
       }
```

how to get power values?

in ScanResult call [getTxPower](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult#getTxPower()) (if your api > 26)

> Note:rssi reliability is not 100%, it may be affected by environmental factors

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am using Bluetooth Classic not Bluetooth low energy (BLE). Does the solution works for bluetooth classic too?

Comment: The API is only applicable to BLE, but the distance calculation can be universal, as long as you can get txpower and rssi

Comment: I checked the documentation and txpower is listed in BLE. Do you know any other that I can get value of txpower or I can get my phone disconnected over a 5m distance from the hardware?

Comment: about disconnect ,you can call getDistance and detect if distance > 5, By closing the streams, you kick off the disconnect process. After you close the socket, the connection should be fully broken down.

Comment: I am getting same distance in meters, no matter from how far I connect my phone to device. Do you know how can I get the distance every second?

Answer (score 0):

```
         short rssi = intent.getExtras().getShort(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI);
         int iRssi = abs(rssi);
         // 将蓝牙信号强度换算为距离
         double power = (iRssi - 59) / 25.0;
         String mm = new Formatter().format("%.2f", pow(10, power)).toString();
```

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String aa = tvDevices.getText().toString() + "";
                if (aa.contains(device.getAddress())) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        short rssi = intent.getExtras().getShort(
                                BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI);
                        int iRssi = abs(rssi);
                        double power = (iRssi - 59) / 25.0;
                        String mm = new Formatter().format("%.2f", pow(10, power)).toString();
                       // tvDevices.append(device.getName() + ":" + device.getAddress() + " ：" + mm + "m" + "\n");
                    }else {

                    }
                }
                // search finished
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                    .equals(action)) {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. By trying your approach, I get a power of 0.00. Do you know any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I added the complete code, hope it will be helpful to you